# Issue with Changing and Restoring Color of Three.js Objects

Tags: three.js, 3d

I am working on a 3D simulation using Three.js and I have run into an issue while trying to highlight and then "unhighlight" objects in my scene.

**Context:**
I have a series of jobs in my simulation, and each job has associated 3D objects. My aim is to highlight a specific job by changing the color of all its associated objects and then revert this change to restore their original color.

**Issue:**
The problem is that after highlighting and "unhighlighting" the object, the color does not properly restore. In some cases, the object even turns black, indicating something is not functioning as it should.

I have tried various approaches, including storing the original color in node.userData.originalColor for later restoration, but so far, nothing has worked as expected.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights into how I could resolve this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

**Code:**
To accomplish this, I have two main functions: highlightJob and unhighlightJob.

*highlightJob* multiplies each color component (R, G, B) of the object by a scalar (in my case, 5) to highlight it.

*unhighlightJob* attempts to restore the object's original color.

```
async highlightJob(job) {
        try {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                // Determine the objects within the job, whether it's a THREE.Group or not
                const objects = job.objects instanceof THREE.Group ? job.objects.children : job.objects;
                for (const object of objects) {
                    object?.traverse(node => {
                      if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh && node.material) {
                        // Store the original color only if it hasn't been stored yet
                        if (!node.userData.originalColor) {
                          node.userData.originalColor = node.material.color.clone();
                        }
                        // Amplify the existing color for highlighting
                        let newColor = node.material.color.clone().multiplyScalar(5);
                        node.material.color.copy(newColor);
                      }
                    });
                }
                resolve();
            });

         } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Error in highlightJob: ${error.message}`);
        }

    }

     

    async unhighlightJob(job) {
        try {
            if(job==null){ return null;}
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                // Determine the objects within the job, whether it's a THREE.Group or not
                const objects = job.objects instanceof THREE.Group ? job.objects.children : job.objects;
                for (const object of objects) {
                    object?.traverse(node => {
                      if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        // Restore the original color
                        if (node.userData.originalColor) {
                          node.material.color.copy(node.userData.originalColor);
                        }
                      }
                    });
                }
                resolve();
            });
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(`Error in unhighlightJob: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you store the colours in `userData` correctly? Please show more of your code, or even better provide a running example.

Comment: Modify the post to add more code. Please review again if you wish.